# node.js project SQL query error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a project started by someone else, and there's a query I need help with. I'm not used to SQL joins, so basically I end up doing something like:

```
WHERE something.id = somethingElse.id
```

The problem with this is if there's no related information in the rest of the tables, then I just don't get the info from the first 2 tables. But I need to get the information from the 2 tables even if there's no related information in the other tables.

Here's my [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/325a3).

Comment: I already managed to do the query for the first 2 tables, what i need is to link the rest of them to the query and still get the same amount of results even though some of them have no related information in them

Comment: Oh, i forgot to say, for the first table in the fiddle... "incidence" table. I need to bring just the one with the highest id number

Comment: When you have that kind of query semantics you need to use a left or right join

Comment: that's just the thing.. I'm not used to joining tables using the actual LEFT or RIGHT or INNER or OUTER or CROSS JOIN

Comment: To better explain myself. I need to bring up results from table devices, and join the other tables in the query. Then for each device_id i need to bring up the last possible record from table incidence

Comment: Here's what i got so far, but i think i might've made it worse...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1972/4
Also I was trying to do the queries with the actual database... if i use MAX at any point, it will just show one row, and if i don't and depending on what else i do, it will show me either all the rows, or the lowest id's and just for one of the devices..
i've also tried with DISTINCT but it will repeat fields with the same value that i didn't want to repeat

Comment: I would suggest to create a stored procedure and collect all necessary information from the different tables, save them into variables and at the end of the stored procedure, return within a single select all collected information.

Comment: The other option would be to work with subqueries and handle the case, where no result in subquery has been found with ISNUNLL()

Comment: yeah, i also thought of doing something like that... i'm still working on it